# Common way to build and deploy a react web project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build

I finished a part of my project and bought a webspace with a domain and a database to publish on. So I create a React-Typescript project with followed structure:

[image]

`API`: has my controllers

`BLL`: the services

**Question** do I have to create a Build and publish it on the webspace, with the API, BLL... or only the Web component? So that the API, BLL... are on a seperate server and the fetches from the Web-Component are via IP:Port address?

What is the common way here?

Comment: Is that a react project? Or is that a backend server project _and_ a react front end project?

Comment: @AlexWayne the "Web" is a react front end project and the Folder "Business" is the backend server project. Do I have to publish the Backend on a seperate server or can I also publish it on the Webspace?

Comment: The in and outs of web hosting is massively large problem space. And the strategies and approaches number in the thousands. I couldn't hope to do justice to that in a single answer. But in short, you probably want them on the same server, and you want your backend to deliver your front end assets to browsers somehow. And your frontend makes requests without a domain like `/api/mydata/` to pull data from the same domain as the frontend. This question will likely get closed now, as it's way too broad to answer.